# How to read dbf with more 255 fields

Tags: php, oledb, dbf

I'm trying to read a .DBF (dBASE for Windows, which has a 1024 field limit) file with 320 fields (columns).

I'm actually using OLEDB for Visual Fox Pro, which has a [limitations of 255 fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/3kfd3hw9(v=vs.80)):

```
$conn->Open('Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source="c:\path";Collating Sequence=GENERAL')
```

It gives me the "not a table" error, but if I open the file with OpenOffice, I delete some columns I can read the file.

Is there any ODBC or other tools to read this file in an automated way?

EDIT: Is there a way, using a script, to delete some columns from a DBF file?

Comment: I don't know about other libraries to read these files, but if they are not there, maybe you can write one. The [dbf file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf) is surprisingly simple.

Comment: I took a look, but it's out of my skills.

Comment: The only other driver I know of that can read beyond VFP defaults is Sybase Advantage Database, but I use within C#, but appears to also have php support as well.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Now I'm trying to discover how to use their OLE DB without purchasing the entire Advantage Database solution.